# update the neighboring input-field only when it is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

wonder if there is a better way to update neighbor input field. I have an idea how I would do it, but I don't think it is best solution to it so would want to get a see if there is an alternative way to do this.

**app.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input placement="First name" [(ngModel)]="firstname" (input)="onNameChange()" />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input placement="Surname" [(ngModel)]="surname" (input)="onNameChange()" />
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input placement="Nickname" [(ngModel)]="nickname" /> 
 </div>
</form>
```

**app.ts**

```
onNameChange: void {
 let firstname=this.firstname.trim();
 let surname=this.surname.trim();
 let remaining=this.nickname.replace(firstname, '').trim();
 remaining=remain.replace(surname, '').trim();
 if (!remaining) {
  let nickName = firstname.concat(' ', surname);
  this.nickname = nickName.trim();
 }
}
```

Ideally, the above code should automatically fill in the nickname when the nickname field is empty, or when it contains only the values from the firstname and surname. Is there a better to do this?

**Possible Outputs:**

```
firstname: Jim
surname: 
nickName: Jim

firstname: Jim
surname: Smith
nickName: Jim Smith

firstname:
surname: Smith
nickName: Smith

// try to enter different value in the firstname and surname fields
// but those fields don't change the nickname field because nickname is 
// not the same as the firstname or surname
firstname: Jim 
surname: Smith
nickName: Tom Smiths 

firstname:
surname: 
nickName: Jim Smith
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your logic is pretty simple, you could use template reference variables like in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rqo3m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

```html
<input #first placement="First name" placeholder="First name" (input)="deactivate ? null : nick.value = first.value.trim() + ' ' + last.value.trim()" />
<input #last placement="Surname" placeholder="Last name" (input)="deactivate ? null : nick.value = first.value.trim() + ' ' + last.value.trim()" />
<input #nick placement="Nickname" placeholder="Nickname" (input)="deactivate = true" />
```

(I simplified the `ngModel`s but you can keep them, depending on what you do with your form).

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I am not sure if your solution works on my situation. I need to consider and stop the changes from `firstname` and `surname` applying on `nickname`, the moment user enters something in the `nickname` field.

Comment: I have edited my answer to take this possibility into account (remember to declare that new variable in your component)